# How can I define the syntax of a C-defined function with with module_make_function?

Tags: doc-strings, modules

I've tried

```c
#define DEFUN(lsym, csym, amin, amax, doc, data) \
  bind_function (env, lsym, env->make_function(env, amin, amax, csym, doc, data))

DEFUN("libgit2-core-status", Flibgit2_status, 1, 1, \
  "\\(fn PATH) libgit2 status test return branch \\(fn PATH)", NULL);
```

but I still get this for `C-h f libgit2-core-status`:

```
libgit2-core-status is a Lisp function.

(libgit2-core-status &rest ARGS)

\(fn PATH) libgit2 status test return branch \(fn PATH)
```

Comment: I think you should drop the backslashes.

Comment: @npostavs That just gives `libgit2 status test return branch (fn PATH)`

Comment: Oh, and also put a newline (inside the string) before the `(fn PATH)` part.

Comment: @npostavs Two newlines did the trick! Care to write that up as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of `(fn ARGS)` syntax is described in [`(elisp) Function Documentation`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Function-Documentation.html):

> ```
>    The last line of the documentation string can specify calling
> conventions different from the actual function arguments.  Write text
> like this:
>
>      \(fn ARGLIST)
>
> following a blank line, at the beginning of the line, with no newline
> following it inside the documentation string.  (The `\' is used to
> avoid confusing the Emacs motion commands.)  The calling convention
> specified in this way appears in help messages in place of the one
> derived from the actual arguments of the function.
> ```

The backslash is a single backslash in a string literal, not a doubled one to produce an actual backslash in the string value.

Since you are writing in C, where string literals must stop at the end of line, you have to use something like `"The function description...\n\n(fn ARGLIST)"`. Since the opening parenthesis doesn't occur in the first column, there's no need to escape it with a backslash (although you can if you want).